# How do I globally change parent slug on custom post type in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I created a new post type in the WordPress `functions.php` file and the default slug is [www.website.com/blog/new-slug](http://www.website.com/blog/new-slug), but I want it to be [www.website.com/new-slug](http://www.website.com/new-slug) only. How do I remove /blog/ from the slug? I have `'hierarchical' => true,` to so the post type acts like pages and also `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'new-slug' ),`, but it is not working, and /blog/ is in the slug for the new post type. Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. No idea why I missed this.

The `rewrite` parameter of the `register_post_type()` function has a parameter of `with_front` that when set to false will not be prepended with the front base specified by the permalink structure.

```
register_post_type( 'cpt', array(
    'rewrite' => array(
        'with_front' => false,
    )
);
```

The above will prevent `/blog/` from being on URLs for your CPT's posts.